# Не компилятся шейдеры. Краш при попытке просмотра лога

Tags: c#, opengl, шейдеры, glsl

Я подгрузил в свою программу 2 шейдера:

Вертексный

```
#version 120
varying vec2 texcoord;
varying vec4 color;

void main() {
    gl_Position = gl_ModelViewProjectionMatrix * gl_Vertex;
    texcoord = vec2(gl_MultiTexCoord0);
    color = gl_Color;
}
```

Фрагментный

```
#version 120
varying vec2 texcoord;
varying vec4 color;
uniform sampler2D texture;
uniform float procent;

void main() {
    vec4 original = texture2D(texture, texcoord);
    float d = (original.r + original.b + original.g)/3.0;
    if (procent < texcoord.y)
        gl_FragColor = vec4(d, d, d, color.a);
    else
        gl_FragColor = original * color;
}
```

При их компиле выдает 0. При попытке получить ошибку, приложение крашится, и среда даже не показывает исключение.
Вот класс шейдера

```
class ShaderProgram {
    private int programID;
    public ShaderProgram() {
        programID = glCreateProgramObjectARB();
    }

    public ShaderProgram addFragment(byte[] data) {
        return add(data, GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER_ARB);
    }

    public ShaderProgram addVertex(byte[] data) {
        return add(data, GL_VERTEX_SHADER_ARB);
    }

    public ShaderProgram add(byte[] data, int shaderType) {
        int shaderID = glCreateShaderObjectARB(shaderType);
        string[] file = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data).Split(new char[] { '\r', '\n' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

        glShaderSourceARB(shaderID, 1, file, null);
        glCompileShaderARB(shaderID);

        int param;
        glGetObjectParameterivARB(shaderID, GL_OBJECT_COMPILE_STATUS_ARB, out param);
        if (param == GL_FALSE) { 
            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
            int hz;
            glGetInfoLogARB(shaderID, 99999, out hz, builder);
            throw new Exception("Shader compilation error!\n" + builder.ToString());
        }

        glAttachObjectARB(programID, shaderID);
        return this;
    }

    public ShaderProgram compile() {
        glLinkProgramARB(programID);

        int link_ok;
        glGetProgramiv(programID, GL_LINK_STATUS, out link_ok);

        if (link_ok == 0) {
            int maxLength;
            int length;
            glGetProgramiv(programID, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, out maxLength);
            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
            glGetProgramInfoLog(programID, maxLength, out length, builder);
            throw new Exception(builder.ToString());
        }
        return this;
    }

    public void start() {
        glUseProgramObjectARB(programID);
    }

    public void stop() {
        glUseProgramObjectARB(0);
    }

    public int getUniform(String name) {
        return glGetUniformLocationARB(programID, name);
    }
}
```

Вот как я создаю свой шейдер

```
        public static ShaderProgram whiteColored;

        public static void RegisterShaders() {
            whiteColored = new ShaderProgram()
                .addVertex(Properties.Resources.texture_color)
                .addFragment(Properties.Resources.white_colored)
                .compile();
        }
```

При вызове `glGetInfoLogARB` приложение крашится, поэтому не могу понять в чем проблема. Сам файл шейдеров читается нормально. Если оставить во фрагментном шейдере только установку цвета - `gl_FragColor = vec4(1.0,0.0,0.0,1.0);`, то он будет работать

Comment: Почему вы проверяете ошибки не через `glGetError` ?

Comment: @Kromster Так было в исходниках, которые я переписал. Вроде так и делают при компиле и линковке шейдеров. Можно попробовать, но как его юзать?

Comment: Это чтобы посмотреть ошибки не только сборки шейдеров, но вообще OpenGL ошибки. Вызываете и смотрите какой код ошибки вернулся. Если 0 - ошибок нет. (P.S. Я кстати использую `glGetShaderInfoLog` для проверки ошибок сборки шейдеров, попробуйте его тоже)

Comment: @Kromster странно, сразу же после неудачной компиляции вызвал glGetError и вернуло 0. Твой метод тоже крашит прогу, как и мой. Что-то очень странно. Наверное что-то с дровами видюхи, хз

Comment: @Minebot А создание и установка контекста у вас без проблем проходит? И нужные расширения поддерживаются? Попробуйте запустить OpenGL тест какой-нибудь.

Comment: @Minebot Возможно шейдеры версии 120 не поддерживают циклы установи #version 330. Еще нужно получить статус компиляции шейдера. Он покажет есть ли ошибка. Если есть ты должен запросить текст и выкинуть исключением с текстом ошибки.

Comment: @Unick Ну у меня все функции openGL нормально работают, рисуют, что надо

Comment: @МихаилГоробец у меня в шейдерах нет циклов. Так я и получаю статус компиляции. Он выдает 0, а вот когда пытаюсь получить лог ошибки, у меня вылетает прога, и даже не хочет выводить исключение. Наверное это исключение на уровне байткода

Comment: @МихаилГоробец вы же обновили драйвер, просто это первое что при таком странно поведении стоит сделать.

Comment: А если не секрет, как вы подключаете OpenGL функции к C#. Я не совсем в курсе этого вопроса, есть ощущение, что вы вызываете функцию лога не правильно.

Comment: @Unick Я использую tao framework, Щас попытаюсь обновить дрова

Comment: Может быть ваш StringBulder должен быть не пустой, а в нём должно быть столько выделено места, сколько вы передаёте во 2 параметре.

Comment: @Unick Да, так и есть. Теперь ошибка корректно выводится и я могу её исправить

Comment: Только теперь при линковке выдает error C5145: must write to gl_Position. Всё перегуглил, так и не понял почему так. gl_Position я вроде задаю в вертексном шейдере

Comment: @Minebot такая ошибка возникает если код шейдера пустой. Значит или `byte[] data` пустой или `string[] file` пустой или `file` не правильно передан в `glShaderSourceARB`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Что бы решить проблему, надо в `glShaderSourceARB` в качестве параметра надо передавать не массив из строчек, а одну единую строчку с разделителем `\r\n` (он установится автоматически, если вы будете считывать строчки с файла). Так же надо указать длину строки. Вот как я начал вызывать `glShaderSourceARB`:

```
string file = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data);
int lenght = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data).Length;
glShaderSourceARB(shaderID, 1, new string[] { file }, ref lenght);
```